# how to hide filepath and page number in gedit for printing

Tags: printing, gedit, source-code

I have to submit report on my project
and i need to print source code but gedit includes file path, filename and page number at the top of the page

how to remove it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could disable printing the page headers when you print the file.

Go to *File -> Print -> Text Editor (tab)* and ***uncheck*** the line that says *Print Page Headers*

[image: screenshot]

Comment: In recent versions of gedit, to get to this settings menu click the three horizontal bars icon, then click the printer icon, then click the "Text Editor" tab.